# How do I create a new data table in Orange?

Tags: python, data-mining, orange

I am using Orange (in Python) for some data mining tasks. More specifically, for clustering. Although I have gone through the tutorial and read most of the documentation, I still have a problem.
All the examples in docs and tutorials assume that I have a tab delimited table with data in it. However, there is nothing saying how one can go about creating a new table from scratch. For example, I want to create a table for word frequencies across different documents.

Maybe I am missing something so if anyone has any insight it'd be appreciated.

Thanks
George

### EDIT:

This is how I create my table

```
#First construct the domain object (top row)
vars = []
for var in variables:
    vars.append(Orange.data.variable.Continuous(str(var)))
domain = Orange.data.Domain(vars, classed) #The second argument indicated that the last attr must not be a class    
#Add data rows assuming we have a matrix 
t = Orange.data.Table(domain, matrix)
```

Comment: hear, hear!  best stuff I found was at:  http://orange.biolab.si/doc/reference/Orange.data.table/ .   Part of why I switched to ``pandas -> R`` (ugh!) as my workflow.

Comment: Orange document is very good now. See  https://orange3.readthedocs.io/projects/orange-data-mining-library/en/latest/tutorial/data.html

Comment: You can use `Orange.data.Table.from_numpy`, which would be suitable here.

Comment: To add a quick helper - If you to to the "Data" tab on the widgets sidebar, and select "Python Script", the default (on 3.30 at least) is already filled out with a python script that creates a table from numpy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This took me hours to figure out. In python, do this:

```
Import Orange
List, Of, Column, Variables = [Orange.feature.Discrete(x) for x in ['What','Theyre','Called','AsStrings']]
Domain = Orange.data.Domain([List, Of, Column, Variables])
Table = Orange.data.Table(Domain)
Table.save('NewTable.tab')
```

I'd tell you what each bit of code does, but as of now I'm not really sure. It's funny that such a powerful toolkit should have such hard to understand documentation, but I suspect it's because it's entire user base has doctorates.

Comment: Well I don't have a doctorate yet I use Orange. But I agree with you. The documentation is amazingly complicated. The problem is that sometimes Orange tries to make life so much harder than it actually is:). I've actually managed to found the solution myself but forgot to post it here. I am gonna do it now but I'll select your answer:)

Comment: We'd appreciate suggestions (or even better, pull-requests with edits) to make it better!

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is indeed insufficient if you ask me. This may not be the answer to the question but it could be helpful to someone else. I tried for hours to create a Table using constructors and Domains and what not, just for an association rule mining task, and finally found out that the easiest way to create a table is simply to write your data to a file with the extension .tab or .basket and create a table from that.

```
Orange.data.Table("yourFile.basket")
```

Of course the structure of the file needs to be correct. See the provided example files located in the Orange package directory inside **datasets/**